# Unhandled internal error. org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.JobControl.addJob

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I installed pig on centos 6. I am new to pig.

I opened pig in local mode using $pig -x local.
only getting error while doing DUMP.
error message is : ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.JobControl.addJob(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/jobcontrol/Job;)Ljava/lang/String;

I have set JAVA_HOME and java version is 1.7. But hadoop is not installed.

=================

```
grunt> A = load '/etc/passwd' using PigStorage(':');                                                                      
grunt> B = foreach A generate $0 as id;                                                                                    grunt> dump B;


2014-06-13 16:24:33,039 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2014-06-13 16:24:33,040 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, NewPartitionFilterOptimizer, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter], RULES_DISABLED=[FilterLogicExpressionSimplifier]}
2014-06-13 16:24:33,041 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MRCompiler - File concatenation threshold: 100 optimistic? false
2014-06-13 16:24:33,042 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2014-06-13 16:24:33,042 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2014-06-13 16:24:33,043 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
2014-06-13 16:24:33,044 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
2014-06-13 16:24:33,044 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3
2014-06-13 16:24:33,052 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler - Setting up single store job
2014-06-13 16:24:33,052 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Key [pig.schematuple] is false, will not generate code.
2014-06-13 16:24:33,053 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Starting process to move generated code to distributed cache
2014-06-13 16:24:33,053 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Distributed cache not supported or needed in local mode. Setting key [pig.schematuple.local.dir] with code temp directory: /tmp/1402656873052-0
2014-06-13 16:24:33,062 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.JobControl.addJob(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/jobcontrol/Job;)Ljava/lang/String;
Details at logfile: /home/ripsme/pig/pig_1402655166073.log
grunt>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: thanks Jens for formatting.I did not know how to format. now it looks pretty well.Thanks for your awesome help.

Comment: Issue Resolved: please do `yum install pig` on a fresh machine.now able to do all operations under `grunt>pig -x local` mode. So no issues now. Previously I downloaded pig tar from apache site and followed the mentioned steps.but got above runtime exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for Redhat systems, pls do

`$sudo yum install pig`

and open pig in local mode. this worked for me.